# Taylor series expansion for $g(t+k,u(t+k))$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am working on predictor corrector schemes for parabolic PDEs and in my derivations I had to find the Taylor series expansion for $g(t+k,u(t+k))$ where $g$ is a function of $t$ and $u$, $u$ is a function of $t$ and $k$ is a time step size. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is essentially a function of one variable: $t$.
Define 
$$f(t) = g(t, u(t)).$$
What you are looking for is the tailor expansion of $f$ around point $t$ with step $k$. To apply the usual formula up to second order
$$f(t+k) = f(t) + f'(t)k + \frac{1}{2}f''(t)k^2 + O(k^3),$$
we only need to calculate the derivatives of $f$.

Using the multivariate chain rule we get:
$$f'(t) = g_t(t, u(t)) + g_u(t, u(t))u'(t)$$
and 
$$f''(t) = g_{tt}(t, u(t)) + 2g_{ut}(t, u(t))u'(t) + g_{uu}(t, u(t))(u'(t))^2 + g_u(t, u(t))u''(t).$$

Plugging in the values of the above equation into the tailor expansion of $f$ gives you the wanted expansion up to the second order.